# How to set number of threads for UDP webflux server?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, netty, spring-webflux

I am building a UDP server in Spring Boot 2.1.3 with Webflux 2.1.8 which collects data from UDP clients.

I wanted it to be built in fully reactive manner but I am facing issues with thread pools. My app currently runs only on one thread which is not what I've expected. First, I've built a simple python client which waits for a response to test my server

```py
# Create a UDP socket at client side
UDPClientSocket = socket.socket(family=socket.AF_INET, type=socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
# Send to server using created UDP socket

UDPClientSocket.sendto(bytesToSend, serverAddressPort)
print("Receiving...")
msgFromServer = UDPClientSocket.recvfrom(bufferSize)
msg = "Message from Server {}".format(msgFromServer[0])

print(msg)
```

Now my Spring boot UDP server looks like this:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    CommandLineRunner serverRunner(UdpDecoderHandler udpDecoderHanlder, UdpEncoderHandler udpEncoderHandler, UdpHandler udpHandler) {
        return strings -> {
            createUdpServer(udpDecoderHanlder, udpEncoderHandler, udpHandler);
        };
    }

    private void createUdpServer(UdpDecoderHandler udpDecoderHandler, UdpEncoderHandler udpEncoderHandler, UdpHandler udpHandler) {
        UdpServer.create()
                .handle((in,out) -> {
                    in.receive().asByteArray().subscribe();
                    return Flux.never();
                })
                .port(19001)
                .doOnBound(conn -> conn
                        .addHandler("decoder", udpDecoderHandler)
                        .addHandler("encoder", udpEncoderHandler)
                        .addHandler("handler", udpHandler)
                )
                .bindNow(Duration.ofSeconds(30));
    }
}
```

Decoder:

```java
@Service
public class UdpDecoderHandler extends MessageToMessageDecoder<DatagramPacket>  {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UdpDecoderHandler.class);

    @Override
    protected void decode(ChannelHandlerContext channelHandlerContext, DatagramPacket datagramPacket, List<Object> out) {
        ByteBuf byteBuf = datagramPacket.content();
        byte[] data = new byte[byteBuf.readableBytes()];
        byteBuf.readBytes(data);
        String msg = new String(data);
        LOGGER.info("Decoded data: " + msg);

        InetSocketAddress s = datagramPacket.sender();
        channelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(s);
    }
}
```

Encoder:

```java
@Service
public class UdpEncoderHandler extends MessageToMessageEncoder {

    @Override
    protected void encode(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object o, List list) throws Exception {
        InetSocketAddress socketAddress = (InetSocketAddress) o;
        log.debug("Encode function...");
        String msg = "Hello response!";
        DatagramPacket response = new DatagramPacket(Unpooled.copiedBuffer(msg.getBytes()), socketAddress);
        list.add(response);
    }
}
```

Handler (here I've added sleep function to test my concurency):

```java
@Service
public class UdpHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {
        log.info("Channel Read function");
        InetSocketAddress message = (InetSocketAddress) msg;

        Thread.sleep(5000);

        ctx.channel().writeAndFlush(message).addListener((GenericFutureListener<Future<Void>>) future -> {
            if(future.isDone() && future.isSuccess()) {
                log.info("OK");
            } else {
                log.error("error " + future.isDone() + " - " + future.isSuccess());
                if(!future.isSuccess()) {
                    future.cause().printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Having such I've run my python scripts at once:

```
python3 udp-client.py & python3 udp-client.py
```

Two messages will pop up with 5s difference which means my app runs on one thread.

How can I customize netty and webflux to work with 4 threads?

Comment: Did you find out the problem? Going to implement a similar PoC solution.

Comment: Unfortunately not. I've implemented UDP socket by hand which accepts incoming connections and creates threads manually.

Comment: I found the answer. UDP is by the nature running in a single thread because there is no connection it needs to handle for a long time. Switching to new threads for every msg is quite expensive on CPU and memory since the UDP server should have thousands of requests per second. So I also implemented my custom solution but with native Java net UDP support and Kotlin coroutines and it's probably the fastest solutions I could found. Also tried to do the same with Golang and Rust.

Comment: Thank for update, do you have a public repo for reference?